# count by rows if there is any instance in any colum in R

Tags: r, count, row

I have a dataframe like so:
df

```
ID  Black  red   blue  green
1     0      1     1     1
2     0      0     2     1
3     0      5     1     2
4     0      0     1     2
5     0      0     1     2
```

with this data, how can I count the columns that have any number regardless of the actual number? Is there any way to do this?

I tried `rowSums(df)` but result is not what I want.

My desired output is:

```
ID  Black  red   blue  green    count
1     0      1     1     1        3
2     0      0     2     1        2
3     0      5     1     2        3
4     0      0     1     2        2
5     0      0     1     2        2
```

thanks in advance!

Comment: Does rowSums(df>0) deliver the desired results? In case id shouldnt be considered df[-1]

Comment: Why are these answers in the comments and not posted as answers below?

Comment: @nsinghs since it was just a short line of code without any explanation i felt it fits better as a coment than an answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this should work for you

```
data = data.frame(Black = rep(0, 5),
                  Red = c(1,0,5,0,0),
                  Blue = c(1,2,1,1,1),
                  Green = c(1,1,2,2,2))


data$count = apply(data, 1, FUN = function(x) length(x[x>0]))
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution:

```
library(dplyr)

data <-
  data.frame(Black = rep(0, 5),
             Red = c(1,0,5,0,0),
             Blue = c(1,2,1,1,1),
             Green = c(1,1,2,2,2)
             )
data$count <-
  data %>%
  apply(2, as.logical) %>%
  rowSums
```

this produces the same result as the answer by [ccharles](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2986028/ccharles), but utilizes a trick that I think is broadly useful. By coercing all values to the logical class (i.e. `TRUE` or `FALSE`), you can collapse all zeros into `FALSE`, and any other number into `TRUE`. Numeric functions treat logical values as `TRUE = 1` and `FALSE = 0`, so you can then use `rowSums()` to get a count for each row.

Comment: They work well! thank you so much